# disk i/o error on multiple disks after format failure

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, fdisk, io

I have 2 3.5" WD20EARS disks. durring a format/wipe, there was a power failure and now i'm unable to access either disk. I would normally think that it's just a dead disk but since it happened on both, I doubt it.

**SMART results say that both disks are OK**

Here are a few things I've tried.

- **parted**

  ```
  $ parted /dev/sdf
  Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdf: Input/output error
  ```
- **fdisk**

  ```
  $ fdisk /dev/sdd
  Welcome to fdisk (until-linux 2.31.1).

  fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdf: Input/output error
  ```
- **formatting using the graphical ubuntu disk utility**

  ```
  Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device '/dev/sdf' (udisks-error-quark, 0)
  ```
- **fsck**

  ```
  $ fsck/dev/sdf

  fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdf
  ```
- **ddrescue** this is able to read the disk but I don't really care about the data on this drive, I just want it working again.
- **hdparm**

  ```
  $ hdparm --verbose --write-sector 3907029168 --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing /dev/sdf
  re-writing sector 3907029168:
  ```

  I don't actually know what I'm doing with this one :p  It's not erroring out but I'm not sure it's actually doing anything.

:::EDIT::: hdparm finally finished. here are the results,

```
sudo hdparm --verbose --write-sector 3907029168 --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing /dev/sdf

/dev/sdf:

APT: No idVendor found -> not USB bridge device

re-writing sector 3907029168: 

oflags.bits.lob_all=0xfc, flags={ nsect lbal lbam lbah dev command }

oflags.bits.hob_all=0x3c, flags={ nsect lbal lbam lbah }

using LBA48 taskfile

outgoing cdb:  85 0b 06 00 00 00 01 e8 b0 00 88 00 e0 e0 34 00

outgoing_data:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

SG_IO: ATA_16 status=0x2, host_status=0x0, driver_status=0x8

SG_IO: sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 10 51 e0 01 21 00 00 00 a0 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 10 51 e0 01 21 00 00 00 a0 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

SG_IO: desc[]:  10 51 e0 01 21 00 00 00 a0 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA_16 stat=00 err=01 nsect=00 lbal=00 lbam=b0 lbah=00 dev=00

succeeded
```

I says succeeded, but nothing appears to have changed

Comment: The problem with green drive, they get damage more easily than black drive. I'd say smart is wrong, the drive is damaged. Possible the drive head didn't auto-park in time and touch the surface during the power failure.

Comment: I was unaware that power loss could cause damage to a drive.  Here is a stackExchange post talks of damage in a brownOut/surge which was not the case here.   https://superuser.com/a/103936/643208.  Is that what you mean? Or are you saying the power loss itself can cause damage?

Comment: Yes, the drive head is floating on air above the surface of the hard disk platter when in use. When power dies, it should by design move the head away from the platter before the air cushion disappears. I believe the green drive doesn't have good enough spring action to move the head away fast enough (this is speculation), as I have green drives that dies in a similar way. The other blue, black WD and one other green drives survive. So it's unlucky that you see this in the both drives you have.